# jQuery gallery with thumbnails, click function only working once

Tags: jquery, class, click, gallery, fade

I am working on a simple jQuery image gallery with thumbnails.

Part of the functionality I want for this is that if you click on the currently showing main gallery slide, `.show`, it removes the class of `show`, fades out and THEN fades in the next slide and adds a class of `show` to it. The relevant thumbnails also change class from inactive to active or vice versa.

The jQuery I am using for this is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.gallery-images .show').click(function() {
        $('.gallery-images .show').removeClass('show').fadeOut(300, function() {
            $(this).next().fadeIn(500).addClass('show');
        });
        $('.gallery .active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive').next().removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    });

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-71" class="content gallery gallery-71">
    <div id="gallery-images-wrapper">
        <div class="gallery-images">
                    <div class='gallery-image show' id='gallery-image-72'>
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
                        <div class='caption'>1st caption</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='gallery-image' id='gallery-image-73' style='display:none'>
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
                        <div class='caption'>2nd caption</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='gallery-image' id='gallery-image-74' style='display:none'>
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
                        <div class='caption'>3rd caption</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='gallery-image' id='gallery-image-75' style='display:none'>
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
                        <div class='caption'>4th caption</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='gallery-image' id='gallery-image-76' style='display:none'>
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
                        <div class='caption'>5th caption</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='gallery-image' id='gallery-image-77' style='display:none'>
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
                        <div class='caption'>6th caption</div>
                    </div>
        </div><!--.gallery-images-->
    </div><!--#gallery-images-wrapper-->
    <div id="gallery-thumbs-wrapper">
        <ul class="gallery-thumbs noscript">
            <li class='gallery-thumb active' id='gallery-thumb-72'><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" /></li>
            <li class='gallery-thumb inactive' id='gallery-thumb-73'><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" /></li>
            <li class='gallery-thumb inactive' id='gallery-thumb-74'><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" /></li>
            <li class='gallery-thumb inactive' id='gallery-thumb-75'><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" /></li>
            <li class='gallery-thumb inactive' id='gallery-thumb-76'><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" /></li>
            <li class='gallery-thumb inactive' id='gallery-thumb-77'><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" /></li>
        </ul><!--.gallery-thumbs-->
    </div><!--#gallery-thumbs-wrapper-->
</div><!--gallery-->
```

Currently this only works the first time you click on the main image, but after that it doesn't seem to be registering anything when I click on the second slide.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fFunx/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $('.gallery-images .gallery-image').on('click',function() {
               if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
                 $(this).removeClass('show').hide(); 
                 $(this).next().addClass('show').show();
                 $('.gallery .active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive').next().removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
               }
        });
    });
```

I don't really know why yours didn't work. I'm curious about that.
To make the fadeIn and Out look better you need to work with absolute positioning so the images won't appear to 'jump'.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. Still not really sure why what I did before didn't work but the `if` statement to check if there is a `show` class seemed to do the trick. I wondered if it was something to do with a conflict between the state of the page when first loaded and the state of the page after you've clicked on something.